# Pass output of an expression to the standard input of another program

Tags: bash

I'm trying to generate some data to pass to another program, which takes the argument from standard input, and requires confirmation of that argument.

How do I do this in bash?

From the manual pages.
"Insert a new [argument] into the [database]... [The program] will read the new [argument] from standard in."

Comment: With a pipe, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to automatize a console application is to use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/). With `autoexpect` you can create the expect script, then you can edit it to make more flexible. The `autoexpect` command is part of `expect` package.

You can also use something like:

```
echo "answer" | program
```

But it will not work if:

- you need to send input at a precise moment of time or
- the program is requiring a terminal or
- you need to change the input base on output of the program.

Comment: would you know what kidn of regular expressions it takes? sed, perl, etc

Comment: It is using TCL Regexp syntax. expect is written in TCL. http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm

Comment: Also you should search the documentation page of you program to figure out if it is not possible to run it unattended.

Comment: hi the password prompt expects a confirmation. how would i do this in expect?

Comment: the code i have is

Comment: #!/usr/bin/expect -f
cd /home/45qjkgq/.password-store
set password "pwgen -y 16 1"
set passname [lindex $argv 0];
exec pass insert $passname
echo $passname $password
expect {
  busy abort
  failed abort
  failed abort
  "Enter the password for $passname:" {
    send $password
  }
  connected
}
interact

Comment: it is not running

Comment: Use `autoexpect` it will create the script for you. You can customize it later.